# C++ : How can I calculate a cost of a method (Algorithm Analysis)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am a beginner of C++ and learning Algorithm Analysis:
I am writing a method which return a row number of a 2d array has most 1's , each rows from the input array are all sorted and hits 0 when all 1's are sort to the front like

```
1,1,1,0,0
1,1,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,0
1,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1
```

the method will return 5 from this array and here is the code:

```
int countone(int a[][]){
int count = 0, column = 0, row = 0, current = 0, max;
bool end = true;
do{
     if(a[row][column]==1)
     {
        current++;
        column++;
     }
     if(a[row][column]==0)
     {
        column=0;
        if(count<current)
        {
           count = current;
           max = row;
           current = 0;
        }
     row++;        
     if(a[row][column] != 1 && a[row][column] != 0)
     {
        end = false;
        return max;
     }
 }
while(end)
```

the code hasn't tested yet so it may contains bug and error, but this is not the main point anyway.
I would like to find out the cost of this method, but I have no idea how to calculate it.

The cost I want is Running time T(n) and Big-Oh notation. If possible, the method should running in O(n) time ( not O(n^2) )

Comment: Define cost.  Clock cycles?  Cache hits/misses?  Execution time?  Big-O notation?

Comment: The cost depends on your hourly rate ;-)

Comment: Your question is pretty vague but I would think going through and counting the number of assignments, indexes, increments (which should be pre- not postincrements btw) on the worst case and average scenarios would be the way to go.

Comment: Do you want to analyze it and calculate its cost? Or do you want to run it and measure its cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Evaluating_run-time_complexity) is how you can evaluate the runtime complexity of your code.For your code, the worst case complexity would be the size of your matrix (i.e. if your code compiles) after you make the `end` false when `row` and `column` equal the size of your matrix.

Comment: I don't think it is true [the complexity is the size of the matrix] in here. I think it is actually `O(infinity)`, if I understood correctly - the stopping condition is once the value of the entree is not 0/1, which is not guaranteed [assume the matrix lays within a memory of size `2^n * 2^m` which was just `memset()`ed to 0. Though I might be missing something...

Comment: I already mentioned in the answer that the complexity is only after he makes `end` false when `row` and `column` equal the size of matrix.

Comment: Then I misunderstood you, and revert my comment.

Answer (score 1):

First write code that is easy to read and understand

```
for(int row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row) {
    for(int col = 0; col < colCount; ++col) {
        if(a[row][col] == 0) {
            if(max > col) {
                 max = col;
                 max_row = row;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

is roughly the same, but you can see easy how often a loop/statement is executed(that is what you actually wont). The outer loop is ran rowCount times the inner at most colCount times(average case depends) for itself but that rowCount times.

Then look what statement costs how much. And multiply it with the number of times it is executed(average-/worst case what you like).

Say the only expensive operation is ++ with. Then you have `rowCount * 1 (outer loop ++row) + rowCount * colCount * 1(inner loop ++col)`.

And you get `rowCount x (colCount + 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, my target is making the running time cost to O(N). That will be O(N^2) if there is a double "for" loop.

Comment: If rowCount and colCount is independent you cant say it's O(N^2). Then it is O(N*M). Best solution for that problem would be O(N*log(M)) when you use a matrix. Though, with a simple array of numbers count O(N) is possible. However, if N is the number of fields in your matrix, the problem is already in O(N)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the sorted property of the array to improve the run time. There is no reason to start over and scan from the first column of each row. Once you've scanned through the 1s until you hit a 0, you know that any subsequent rows will not have a longer string of 1s unless they have a 1 in the column where the 0 was found. You can traverse the matrix in a stepwise manner, scanning right until hitting a 0, and scanning down until hitting a 1. Stop once you've hit the right or bottom edge of the array.

```
    int maxRow = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (;;) {
            if (a[i][j] == 0) {
                    // Try moving down one row
                    if (++i >= rowCount) break;
            } else {
                    // New record row length
                    maxRow = i;
                    // Try moving over one column
                    if (++j >= colCount) break;
            }
    }
    return maxRow;
```

Note that the output is 0-based, so for the example matrix the result will be row 4 (not 5) as the row with the most 1s.

The number of matrix elements scanned will be at most: T(n, m) = n + m - 1, which is O(n+m).
If the matrix is square (m = n), then T(n) = 2n - 1, which is O(n).